# Python web scrape from multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to pull data from various columns in the odds table from this website:

https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nba-basketball/totals/?date=20190419

I have tried using the following code but I am only getting the open lines. I want to be able to get exact columns. For example, the pinnacle and bookmaker columns.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

theurl = "https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nba- 
basketball/totals/?date=20190419"
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")

for lines in soup.findAll('span',{"class":"_3Nv_7"}):
    print(lines.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

theurl = "https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nba-basketball/totals/?date=20190419"
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")

for lines in soup.findAll('span',{"class":"_3Nv_7 opener"}):
    print(lines.get_text())
```

Comment: Did you make any changes?

Comment: add opener in the class and change import  of  bs4

Comment: I am already getting the opener with the code I used. I am wanting the different columns of data. Like the pinnacle column.

Comment: do you want all cols  !!

Comment: No just certain columns, like the pinnacle column